# Prove that R is an equivalence relation.

Tags: equivalence-relations

> Let $A$ be the set of integer ordered pairs.
>
> Define relation $R$ on $A$ by $(a,b)R(c,d)$ $\iff$ $a+d = b+c$.
>
> Prove that $R$ is an equivalence relation.

Comment: Please format your question and describe what you tried and where you are stuck.

Comment: An equivalence relation has 3 properties (by definition).  What are they?  How would you test each.  Does R have any or all of these properties?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Reflexive

$a+b=b+a\implies (a,b)$R$(a,b)$

- Symetric

$a+d=b+c\implies c+b=d+a$
$\implies (c,d)$R$(a,b)$

- Transitive

$a+d=b+c$ and $c+f=d+e$
$ \implies a+d+c+f=b+c+d+e$

$\implies a+f=b+e\implies$
 $(a,b)$R$(e,f)$.

Answer (score 0):

If you can find a function $f$ such that $f(a,b) = f(c,d)$ **iff** $(a,b)R(c,d)$ then you can show that $R$ is an equivalence relation (because,
in some sense, you have reduced to the problem to a known equivalence relation $=$).

The equivalence relation in the question suggests a fairly straightforward $f$.